Find the shortest path out the forest; you know the distance, but not the direction!
This is a problem that my classical mechanics professor gave, which I enjoyed tackling; have fun!

Consider the edge of a forest (an infinite line in a plane). You walk $1$ unit directly into the forest, fall down, and forget which way you came from. There are many finite paths that guarantee that you will exit the forest; the most intuitive is to walk one unit in any direction, and then trace a circle of radius of $1$ centered at the place you fell:

This guarantees you will exit after walking
$$1+2\pi\approx 7.28$$
in the worst case scenario.

What is the shortest such path?


Math.SE isn't the place to post a challenge like this. That said, it's good of you to indicate that you've already tackled the problem. (Some people don't, which opens the possibility for someone to spend time concocting, formatting, and perhaps illustrating a comprehensive solution only to get the reply, "Yep! That's how I did it." (Or worse: "That's how I did it. I want a different method.")) I recommend posting your soln as an answer so that others know not to bother posting their own if they match. (Revealing the shortest length in your question would at least let others check their work.)

What's wrong with this argument?: If the convex hull of your path doesn't include the whole circle of radius 1, then you aren't guaranteed to exit the forest; the shortest path with convex hull $S$ is the boundary of $S$; so the suggested "intuitive" path is optimal.

@Blue Why is this not the right site? This is a calculus problem, I assure you...

@Karl If you like, I have added my solution as an answer (if you don't mind a spoiler)

Oh, I see, my second step is wrong. A U shape has convex hull containing a disk but is shorter than the perimeter of the disk.

@DavidRaveh: Why is this not the right site? ... Math.SE is primarily for people asking for help finding answers they don't already know. (The puzzle tag used to state explicitly that one shouldn't "riddle" others. That wording is gone, but the tag still says that it's for asking questions about "principles behind puzzles [etc]" (emphasis mine).) Anyway ... The only problem is that too many challenges look like appeals for help (and thus waste helpers' time). Yours doesn't, so I'm okay with it. Others may not be, though, so I was just suggesting how to make it a better fit. ... Cheers!

You are allowed to share knowledge on this site by posting a question and answer of your own and accepting the answer. Problems that the OP has solved are therefore welcome. Do make an effort to make sure your question hasn’t been asked before

Here was my answer, which I cannot prove is optimal:

Following the red points from $1$ to $6$ allows one to obtain a path length as a function of the extra distance one travels away from the circle; one can show that minimizing the total path length gives: $$1+\sqrt{3}+7\pi/6\approx 6.397$$ for the path length, an improvement. But I cannot prove this is the best path; it is possible the best one is to return inside the circle. Can anyone else improve upon this answer?

Are you only allowed to walk in straight lines with occasional turns?

How does this path meet the potential frontier at $y = -(x + \sqrt{2})$? or $x = -1$?  You might label your points (perhaps with PlotLabels or VertexLabels) to clarify which blue line segments/arcs are traversed in which order in your plot.  (You might also make the non-traversed components more subdued, like gray and/or dashed or dotted.)

@badjohn You are allowed to follow any continuous path; the original solution (in the question) was to go in a circle, and in this answer we travel along the circle for part of it.

Still not seeing how this exits the forest if the frontier is tangent to the unit circle anywhere from the northwest to the southwest.

@EricTowers for the part you describe, I walk along the circle, exactly like I do in the simple solution in the question; it doesn't exit the forest, but it gets you to the very edge, which is sufficient (an infinitesimaly bigger circle would exit the forest)

Ah.  So you don't take the shorter arc between 4 and 5...

This is proven in "An optimal search pattern" from J.R. Isbell
